# In local, environment variable passed with IntelliJ is not working in spring boot batch

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

I am using Spring Boot Gradle plugin and developing in Intellij on Mac,

I'm trying to get value passed with environment variable but can not able to get it,
(Passing 3 variables, among them only one systemDate is not able to access).

Environment variable settings in Intellij are as below.
[image]

I had also tried to set it as a Override configuration properties in IntelliJ as below,
[image]

Code where I am accessing it is as below.

```
String systemDate = Objects
        .toString(chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters().get("systemDate"), "");
```

※Same code is working in staging environment.
In staging I am passing systemDate like below,

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=stg -Dspring.batch.job.names=abcPaymentJob -jar /var/lib/jenkins/deploy/stg/newAbcBatch.jar systemDate=2022-10-20T10:15:30
```

Comment: how you are  passing env variables in staging? via application.properties? Can you please share that file. Also please share what error you are facing in local while accessing this variable

Comment: @AshishPatil updated question with staging command. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting those key/value pairs as environment variables but you are trying to get them as job parameters here:

```
chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters()
```

Job parameters and environment variables are two different things. You either need to:

- pass those key/value pairs as job parameters. On the command line those should be passed like `jar -jar myjob.jar systemDate=2022-10-20T10:15:30`. In IntelliJ, the equivalent is to pass them as "Program arguments" under the "Run/Debug Configuration -> Build and run" section
- or update your code to get values from the environment with `System.getenv("systemDate");` or via Spring's [environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) support

Comment: I had also tried to set them in Override configuration properties option of IntelliJ but it was not working, updated question, please check. Is there any other way to pass systemDate without modifying code?

Comment: You should use "Program arguments", not "Override configuration properties". I updated the answer with an example.